# Post content overflows on my mobile phone

Tags: functions, css

My post contents (single.php) overflows on my mobile phone so the page is wider than phone's screen.

Post Example:

http://www.migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/2020/02/23/work-with-a-team/

I used to bootstrap 4 for grid system

Single.php code snippet which contains after parallax section:

*I am sorry for undeleted comment lines.*

```
<div class="container-fluid single-post">
    <!-- Control the column width, and how they should appear on different devices -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-10 col-md-10">

            <main role="main">
                <!-- section -->
                <section>

                    <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                        <!-- article -->
                        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                            <!-- post thumbnail -->
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if Thumbnail exists ?>
                                <!-- <a href="<?php //the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php //the_title(); ?>"> -->
                         <!--   <div class="parallax" style="background-image: url("<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>");"></div>-->
                            <div style="height:100%;">
                              <!--  <?php //the_post_thumbnail(); // Fullsize image for the single post ?> -->
                                </a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <!-- /post thumbnail -->

                            <!-- post title -->
                            <h1>
                                <!--    <a href="<?php //the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php //the_title(); ?>"><?php //the_title(); ?></a>-->
                            </h1>
                            <!-- /post title -->


                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-1 left-toltip">
                                    <?php global $post; ?>
                                    <div class="sticky-top ">
                                        <a class="tooltips" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>">
                                          <img  src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/facebook.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img2">
                                          <span>Facebook</span>
                                      </a>
                                      <a class="tooltips" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>">
                                          <img  src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/twitter.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img2">
                                          <span>Twitter</span>
                                      </a>
                                      <?php $pinterestimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?>
                                      <a class="tooltips" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&media=<?php echo $pinterestimage[0]; ?>&description=<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                          <img  src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/pinterest.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img2" >
                                          <span>Pinterest</span>  
                                      </a>

                                      <a class="tooltips" href="#see">
                                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/iconfinder_eye-24_103177 (1).png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img2">
                                           <span><?php _e( 'You should see', 'html5blank' ); ?></span>
                                      </a>

                                        <a class="tooltips" href="#cost">
                                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/iconfinder_currencysvg_1579795.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img2">
                                            <span><?php _e( 'Costs', 'html5blank' ); ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="tooltips" href="#budget">
                                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/iconfinder_58_2529974.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img2">
                                            <span><?php _e( 'Budget Tips', 'html5blank' ); ?></span>
                                        </a>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-11" >


                            <?php the_content(); // Dynamic Content ?>



                            <?php  edit_post_link(); // Always handy to have Edit Post Links available ?>

                                    <?php if ( function_exists( 'wpsabox_author_box' ) ) echo wpsabox_author_box(); ?>

                            <?php comments_template(); ?>


                                </div>

                        </article>
                        <!-- /article -->

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php else: ?>

                        <!-- article -->
                        <article>

                            <h1><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h1>

                        </article>
                        <!-- /article -->

                    <?php endif; ?>






                </section>
                <!-- /section -->
            </main>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2" id="right-sidebar" style="background-color:orange; float: right; right: 0!important; width: 100%;">

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        </div>


    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `style.css` you have the following on line 580:

```
.container-fluid.single-post {
     width: 1280px;
}
```

You have to add media queries and adjust this size at different breakpoints or just try changing that to:

```
.container-fluid.single-post {
         width: 100%;
    }
```

That takes care of most of it, but then lower down you have a textarea that has `col="45"` which still makes the content wider than the screen on phones.  So that should be changed to be either something like `col="40"` or better still, try to remove the col attribute all together and instead in the style.css add:

```
.comments textarea#comment{
     width:100%;
}
```

I imagine you'll encounter this issue frequently and will need to adjust these pixel specific widths to percentages for a truly fluid layout.

Also, that giant cursor hand is killing me.